# mouseReleaseEvent not always called | PyQt5

Tags: qt, events, pyqt5

Here is an example of a simple PyQt5 Program, that adds a QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView and then adds a custom EllipseItem. That EllipseItem inherits from QGraphicsEllipseItem and does nothing more than to implement the mousePressEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent() methods.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsEllipseItem, \
    QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent
import sys


class EllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0, 0, 100, 100)
        # self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        # self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent') -> None:
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        print("Mouse Pressed")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent') -> None:
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        print("Mouse Released")


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.title = "mouse Release"
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600

        # Init UI
        self.canvas = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphics_view = QGraphicsView(self.canvas, self)
        self.graphics_view.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        self.canvas.addItem(EllipseItem())

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My Problem is, that the mouseReleaseEvent() method is not called as expected, it depends on the implementation of mousePressEvent() and the flags that are set.

When only printing, without calling super().mousePressEvenet(event), all works fine, mouseReleaseEvent() is called:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent') -> None:
    print("Mouse Pressed")
```

Output when clicking on the Ellipse:

```
Mouse Pressed
Mouse Released
```

When Adding the call to the super method, mouseReleaseEvent() is not called:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent') -> None:
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    print("Mouse Pressed")
```

Output when clicking on the Ellipse:

```
Mouse Pressed
```

When setting the QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable or QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable Flag in **init**(), mouseReleaseEvent() is called and everything is fine. The thing is, I don't want the Item to be movable or selectable, I need to implement those methods myself.

Can I set some other option, so that the mouseReleaseEvent() is called as expected?

Comment: You've already answered your question: don't call `super().mousePressEvent(event)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a fix that works for me.
@musicamante gave me the Idea, not to call `super().mousePressEvent(event)`.
I had discarded that idea previously, because my class in question inherits from another custom class. Its `mousePressedEvent()` method is not called automatically, so I need to call `super().mousePressedEvent()` for it to trigger.

The trick for me is, to call `super.mousePressedEvent()` only, when I'm not inheriting from a build-in class, like `QGraphicsEllipseItem`. In the class, that inherits directly from a build-in class, I have my functionality, but don't call `super().mousePressedEvent()` (I did the same thing for all other mouseEvents).

Comment: "I had discarded that idea previously, because my class in question inherits from another custom class": we cannot help you if you leave out important aspects of your code, and that aspect is of *extreme* importance when asking a question like this, since `super()` always call the base implementation in the MRO. A release event can only be received when the object *grabs* the mouse; so, just do it: call `event.accept()`. Please take your time to read more about Qt event handling. Also, it's `mousePressEvent`, not "mousePressedEvent": syntax is important, be more careful about it.